# How to write REST API method to consume json format for json objects using jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey, jax-rs

I've a `myObject` pojo and list of type `myObject` as shown below:

```
public static final GenericType<List<myObject>> myObjectList = new GenericType<List<myObject>>() {};
```

Below is the method which is used to hit rest api in class `RestClient`:

```
public <P> List<P> getAllOriginal(String resourcePath, GenericType<List<P>> entityType) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(this.baseUri, "target cannot be null");
        return this.client
                .target(this.baseUri)
                .path(resourcePath)
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .cookie("mySSO", getCookie())
                .get()
                .readEntity(entityType);
    }
```

This is how I'm trying to get the data:

```
list = restClient.getAllOriginal("myObject",myObjectList).
                    stream().map(PojoAction::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Below is my json that I receive from REST API:

```
  {
  
  "myObject" : [ {
    "key" : {
      "srcSys" : "REPO_1",
      "srcSysRef" : "20200909_1911_1"
    },
    "productData" : {
      "id" : null,
      "number" : null,
      "isn" : null,
      "productId" : null,
      "productAdditionalData" : {
        "assetClassTree" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
        "description" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
        "productTypeData" : {
          "productType" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
          "productGroup" : "UNCLASSIFIED"
        }
      }
    },
    "state" : "OPEN",
    "type" : "01"
  }, {
    "key" : {
      "srcSys" : "REPO_2",
      "srcSysRef" : "20200403_3892_1"
    },
    "productData" : {
      "id" : "1",
      "number" : "11",
      "isn" : "null",
      "productId" : 1234,
      "productAdditionalData" : {
        "assetClassTree" : "xyz",
        "description" : "abc",
        "productTypeData" : {
          "productType" : "UNCLASSIFIED",
          "productGroup" : "UNCLASSIFIED"
        }
      }
    },
    "state" : "OPEN",
    "tradAcctType" : "01"
  } ]
  }
```

Error :

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.gs.liquidity.pojo.cash.CommitmentPojo>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1442) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1216) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1168) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:332) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:265) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1682) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:977) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:814) ~[jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.1.jar:2.10.1]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:?]
    ... 34 more
```

My analysis:
I understand this error is due to mismatch of data. I'm trying to fetch list but api is giving me object. But I'm not sure how do I fetch object as I'm quite new to REST and jersey. I tried to google, but couldn't find anything significant.
Can you please direct me to some docs or any examples.

I found some related questions:
[How to write a REST API method for which consume json format for list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304240/how-to-write-a-rest-api-method-for-which-consume-json-format-for-list-of-objects)

But I cannot modify the output from REST API as I'm consuming external api.

Comment: I suggest you just practice with Jackson how to properly map JSON to Java classes. Play around with different JSON. You will need to know how to do this, otherwise, you will have to ask a question for every new JSON you have. What you can do to start is create different POJOs and serialize them with the ObjectMapper and see the JSON they produce. The JSON should deserizlie back to the POJO.